# Is there a set of given cardinality and given rank?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $\alpha$ is a cardinal and $\beta$ an ordinal, is it possible to find a set with cardinal $\alpha$ and rank $\beta$ (let us say that the rank of $x$ is the minimum of the ordinals $\gamma$ such that $x\in V_\gamma$) ?

If this question is too hard or the answer is no, if $\beta$ is an ordinal, is there a set of cardinality $\omega$ which has a rank $r$ such that $r\geq\beta+\omega$ ?

Comment: Trivially, of course, $|\beta|$ must be $\geq\alpha$.  I presume from mention of cardinality that you're assuming Choice?

Comment: Yes I assume it. But I do not understand why $\lvert\beta\rvert$ should be $\geq\alpha$.

Comment: You're right; that was a silly slipup on my part.

Answer (score 2):

There is a concept of $\beth$ numbers, which correspond to $\aleph$ numbers when we consider successors to be taken as power sets rather than "next initial ordinal". That is, $$\beth_0=\aleph_0; \beth_{\alpha+1}=2^{\beth_\alpha}; \delta\text{ limit},\ \beth_\delta=\sup\{\beth_\alpha\mid\alpha<\delta\}.$$

Now we can prove the following, $|V_{\omega+\alpha}|=\beth_\alpha$.

So given a cardinal $\alpha<\beth_\gamma$, we can find a set $x\in V_{\omega+\gamma}$ such that $|x|=\alpha$. And since your definition of rank implies that no set has a rank which is a limit ordinal, if $\gamma=\beta+2$ then we can replace an element of $x\in V_\gamma$ by $V_\beta$ and thus ensure that $x$ has rank exactly $\gamma$.

For the more specific question, certainly. Think of any tail segment of any ordinal $r\geq\beta+\omega$.

Comment: There are some things I do not understand in your answer. Has the set x you find cardinal $\alpha$ and rank $\gamma$ (this may be confusing because in the question the rank ought to be $\beta$) ? I understand that we can find a set $x\in V_{\omega+\gamma+1}$ such that $\lvert x\rvert=\alpha$, but I do not understand why we can find one in $V_{\omega+\gamma}$. Then, if $\gamma$ is a rank, it can be written $\gamma=\beta+1$, but why can it be written $\gamma=\beta+2$ ?